# MetadataService.DeployOptions testLevel in Apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, metadata-api, metadata, deployment

I'm using MetadataAPI to activate a Process Builder flow from Apex code, even I'm specifying the testLevel option, it still giving me this error:

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations faultcode=sf:INVALID_OPERATION

```
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service        = createService();
    MetadataService.DeployOptions deployOptions = new MetadataService.DeployOptions();
    deployOptions.allowMissingFiles = false;
    deployOptions.autoUpdatePackage = false;
    deployOptions.checkOnly         = false;
    deployOptions.ignoreWarnings    = false;
    deployOptions.performRetrieve   = false;
    deployOptions.purgeOnDelete     = false;
    deployOptions.rollbackOnError   = true;
    deployOptions.testLevel         = 'RunAllTestsInOrg';
    deployOptions.singlePackage     = true;
```

I would like if there something I'm not specifying or if there's a configuration I should use in order to make it work.

Note: It is working good in developer and non production environments.

Comment: Are you deploying any `Apex` components alongside? You can only choose to not run tests if your deployment is completely devoid of them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The interesting part is the testLevel is set to 'RunAllTestsInOrg', but the deployment is receiving 'NoTestRun'.

Comment: Sorry guys, looking to see if there were more instances of that class in the code, I found for some reason this same code duplicated not running any test, so I delete the code that is not used and adjusted the last version with this the same as above and it worked.